# In Maven, what is the difference between a unit test and an integration test?

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am adding basic regression testing to a Maven project that has no automated testing. My initial idea was to create a number of test classes, called `IT<whatever>.java`, to run in the `integration-test` phase. However, during `package`ing we do obfuscation and optimization and I want to be sure that the tests run against the final `JAR` (or at least the final classes).

The thing is, I can't tell from reading the docs what the actual difference is between the two kinds of test. The docs mention that `integration-test` is run after `package`, which sounds promising, but the tests are excluded from the `JAR` so it's unlikely they're running against the final artifact. Are they run against the `package`d classes? Or is the only distinction between the two test types that they are run in different phases of the build lifecycle?

Comment: First writing unit tests ist best start.. integration tests can be written yes but should be named `*IT.java`... also I would question using obfuscation and optimization (which kind of ?) ...`but the tests are excluded from the JAR`? What does that mean? The best optimization which exists is the run on the JVM...

Comment: Unit tests are not the goal here -- the idea is to validate, as quickly as possible, the proper functioning of the entire system.
The goal of the obfuscation is to prevent decompilation. It's an intellectual-privacy concern.
When I say "the tests are excluded", that means that we do not ship test code in the final product.
Truthfully, I know that we run `proguard` optimization. I am not knowledgeable enough to know exactly what that entails.

Comment: Obfuscation does not prevent decompilation. If you fear that make a licence agreement for using it and check for a license key. Anything else is waste of time. The test code should of course not in the product.  If you run your integration tests via failsafe you can see in the debugging output that the jar is used for testing. The question is what you really like to test and how? Also those tests are running in different phase to make difference in consumed time and what kind of tests they are running...

Comment: @khmarbaise This is not really my area, but I thought that obfuscation essentially made it much more difficult to **read** the decompiled code. Is that not the case? 
We **DO** have both a license agreement and license keys, FWIW.

Comment: In the end the compiled class must be able to run on a JVM which has a fixed/defined format. In consequence the code can be decompiled. It might make it (bit) difficult but much more? It makes your process harder and more time consuming (which costs money).. And (I'm biased here) why not making your code open source and sell the license.. and consulting (it is possible?).. Do you really need proguard? Does it run on Android? If not which optimization can proguard provide in contradiction to good written/tested code which is optimized during the run on the JVM (new JVM's improved speed!)...